# JSF 2.1 calling bean method form url in external application

Tags: jsf-2

I have a link in a external site abc.xhtml which when clicked should go to a method of the managed bean of application so I could populate my page. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: For JSF 2.2 use viewParam and viewAction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792950/how-to-call-a-managed-bean-method-from-an-outputlink/21794116#21794116

Comment: Better one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for